# tick mark line styling with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

Is there a way to select all of the tick mark lines and make them dashed? I tried selecting all lines, but that only got me halfway there. Here's my code so far:

http://jsbin.com/zosihajari/edit?js,output

What I would do is to get hold of the vertical lines, make them grey and dashed but also if possible offset them a little off the axis line so they don't start/end at the bottom/top of the svg space. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `outerTickSize` to zero:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .innerTickSize(-(height-20));
```

Here is your JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jepudifowu/1/edit?css,js,output

Comment: One thing that I would ask, is there a way to offset the vertical dash lines from the Horizontal Axis line? I would like them to start above the axis line so those never touch.

Comment: They are just SVG elements, you can translate them.

Comment: Specifically add "transform: translateY(10px)"; to axis/text and axis/path